# How to get rid of string quotes when printing a list?

Tags: python

I have the following method to print a nested list:

```
def stringify(self, item=None):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return [self.stringify(subitem) for subitem in item]
    if isinstance(item, Token):
        return str(item)
```

And it prints the item like this based on its `__str__` method:

```
["<PLUS: '+'>", "<NUMBER: '2.0'>", ["<TIMES: '*'>", "<NUMBER: '3.0'>", "<NUMBER: '4.0'>"]] ["<USER_DEFINED: 'factorial'>", "<NUMBER: '5.0'>"]
```

However, I don't want it to show the `"` around the item itself. That is, I want it to print like this instead:

```
[<PLUS: '+'>, <NUMBER: '2.0'>, ...
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end you are returning a list of strings instead of converting the list to a string. `list.__str__` always calls `repr` on its elements, so you get the explicit quote marks. To avoid that, you can use `str.join` to bypass `repr`:

```
if isinstance(item, list):
    return '[' + ', '.join(self.stringify(subitem) for subitem in item) + ']'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this by adding the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method onto the `Token` object:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self) # redirect for __repr__ --> __str__
```

And now you won't even need to call `str(item)` in your `stringify` method, and can change it to just returning the object itself:

```
def stringify(self, item=None):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return [self.stringify(subitem) for subitem in item]
    if isinstance(item, Token):
        return item     # do not need str(item) anymore
```

And running it you'll now get:

```
# [<PLUS: '+'>, <NUMBER: '2.0'>, [<TIMES: '*'>, <NUMBER: '3.0'>, <NUMBER: '4.0'>]] [<USER_DEFINED: 'factorial'>, <NUMBER: '5.0'>]
```